# What Fruit Am I?

Tags: riddle

A riddle my math teacher asked back in 10th grade:

> I am a fruit. If you take away the first letter of my name I become a crime. Take away the first two letters of my name I become an animal. Take away the first and last letter of my name and I become a form of music. What am I?

Comment: Very suitable joke for a teacher to tell 15 year olds...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are a:

> **GRAPE**

*If you take away the first letter of my name I become a crime.*

> Removing the 'G' gives *RAPE* (though I have to be honest, using this serious word frivolously in a riddle makes me uncomfortable - you could perhaps clue this using the crop instead...)

*Take away the first two letters of my name I become an animal.*

> Removing 'GR' gives *APE*.

*Take away the first and last letter of my name and I become a form of music.*

> Removing 'G' and 'E' gives *RAP*.

Comment: The serious word you are talking about is the name of a place in Sussex, England - and it can be used as a metaphor, such as "the rape of the natural world", as well as the plant you mention....  regardless, I think we should disassociate the word from the vile act when playing word games or puzzles that involve words - same should apply for words like murder and torture - it is the act that should be abhorred, not the word itself

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @Jimmery. While I agree to an extent about dissociation I also have to respectfully disagree a bit (which I'm sure you won't mind). I don't feel we should try to normalise *this* word *in a casual, flippant context*. While (still very serious) crimes like murder might have been more commonly de-sensitised to a publicly accepted level for many centuries now (enabling the entire murder mystery genre, for example) crimes of a sexual nature are still considered very personally distressing for victims. Personally I just feel if it can be avoided in a puzzle, it should be...

Comment: @Stiv So rape is a more serious or egregious crime than murder? I don't follow your logic at all here, I guess that's why you say "I feel" a lot. I feel like you're making an absurd exception to disassociation of a word on an arbitrary interpretation of current social norms without concern for the long term effect it has on society. Rape as a word shouldn't be shied away from, nor should calling it a crime in a riddle... It's a horrid thing, but hiding in fear of a word, come on.

Comment: @Stiv I understand your aversion to the word - however I would caution against avoiding issues that we find unpleasant or abhorrent - taboo issues often continue regardless, albeit without the public attention required to mitigate or eliminate the issue itself - however this is a discussion best had on another forum

Comment: @Jimmery Re 'another forum', agreed. It's a very valid discussion to have, but yes here in a comments thread on a puzzle is not the best place. Thanks for engaging - I take your point, even if we do approach this from different angles. *To other (or future) commenters:* I shall not be commenting further on this topic here on this thread; if you wish to discuss puzzle-related themes further with other members of this community, consider posting in [meta](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/) or [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/). Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I am a fruit.

> Grape

If you take away the first letter of my name I become a crime.

> Rape

Take away the first two letters of my name I become an animal.

> Ape

Take away the first and last letter of my name and I become a form of music.

> Rap